# Python Predicting column titles according to column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of CSV files consisting different column names but similar data, for example:

---

```
account  name    address
   1      2         3     
   4      5         6
```

---

```
lookup  accountname accountaddress
   7      8         9     
   10     11       12
```

where `account` and `lookup` are the same fields, `name` and `accountname` are the same and so on. Is there a way in which I can normalize or classify all of these into one common column name? I'm not able to map this into a hash because the column names are never similar, every time there's a new file, the name of the column is different, and the order in which they appear in the table are also different.

Comment: For each file are column indices same?

Comment: can you show  expected result

Comment: The data you have provided against the column names, are they in same format, i mean if it matches probably you can get a solution, is the example data exact?

Comment: @anky_91 Yes, the formats are the same. I just need a way to change the column names to a common name.

Comment: @NagaKiran The result would be common column names like "Account number Name Address"

Comment: if columns names atleast have some specific words name , address in common, you can try of using regex in segregating as individual @kaundinya5

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

1. parse your csv data using dictreader

   `row_list = []
   with open(file_path) as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=<field separator>, fieldnames=[<columnslist>])
    for row in cf:
        tmp_row = collections.OrderedDict()
        for column in cf.fieldnames:
             tmp_row[column] = row[column]
             row_list.append(tmp_row)
    return row_list`

And then dump this object `row_list` into csv file using dictwriter.